# Offloading Tkinter GUI to another thread on a Mac OS gives hanging window

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, tkinter

For the purpose of students using a relatively simple GUI library for their assignments I need to offload the GUI to another thread (and use queues to transfer data between them for thread safety). However the code I use works just fine on Windows and Linux but gives a blank hanging screen on a Mac OS X (processing does actually continue but the only way to close the generated window is by force quitting it).

I narrowed the problem in the library down to a few lines of code:

```
import Tkinter
import threading

class MyFactory(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    self.mainroot = Tkinter.Tk()
    self.mainroot.mainloop()

MyFactory().start()
```

Adjusting the code to let the init() call start() had no effect either:

```
import Tkinter
import threading

class MyFactory(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.start()

  def run(self):
    self.mainroot = Tkinter.Tk()
    self.mainroot.mainloop()

MyFactory()
```

Changing the position of the creation of the window (calling Tk()) only gives threading errors (as it should).

The used environments have been Mac OS 10.6.8 and 10.8 respectively with Python 2.6.3 and 2.7.3. A restriction is to not use Python 3.0 or higher (though if that would be the only way to fix it I'll have some work to do).

Simple test programs that do not use additional threads do work though.

The question is how to fix this for the Mac OS?

Comment: I ran into this same problem today on Python 3.5.2 on Mac OS 10.11

Comment: Apparently [QT has problems running on the background thread on a Mac](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/36635-What-is-the-quot-main-thread-quot-Why-is-it-special?s=d57f7bbed029b7a0285538ef8fc9ef18&p=168814#post168814) as well

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to fix it is to run your tkinter code in the main thread. Tkinter wasn't designed to work with threads.

Comment: As much as I would want to do that, the students import this GUI library and therefore always have the main thread when testing/executing their programs. The odd thing is that here Tkinter already has its own thread and should execute as intended. Also when adding GUI elements it keeps the blank screen until you move some other screen over it (and away again) to reveal the graphics.